# Corona SDK composer - changing scenes doesn't work

Tags: sdk, lua, coronasdk

I have a little problem with corona SDK composer API. I got 3 .lua files- main.lua, character.lua and job.lua. The problem is, when I run the game, it automatically transits to character.lua and everything's fine. Then I'm transiting to job.lua and it works as well, but when I'm trying to come back to character.lua- nothing happens (the background doesn't change).That's how it look like:

main.lua:

```
local composer = require("composer")
composer.gotoScene("character")
```

character.lua:

```js
local composer = require( "composer" )

local scene = composer.newScene()

-- -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- All code outside of the listener functions will only be executed ONCE unless "composer.removeScene()" is called.
-- -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

-- local forward references should go here

-- -------------------------------------------------------------------------------


-- "scene:create()"
function scene:create( event )

    local sceneGroup = self.view

    -- Initialize the scene here.
    -- Example: add display objects to "sceneGroup", add touch listeners, etc.
  
local widget = require("widget")


local bottomTabButtons ={
    {  width=32, height=32, defaultFile="character.png", overFile="character_active.png", selected="true"},
    {  width=32, height=32, defaultFile="job.png", overFile="job_active.png", onPress=function() composer.gotoScene( "job" )end},
}
local bottomBar = widget.newTabBar{
     top = display.contentHeight-40,

    buttons = bottomTabButtons
}




end


-- "scene:show()"
function scene:show( event )

    local sceneGroup = self.view
    local phase = event.phase

    if ( phase == "will" ) then
        -- Called when the scene is still off screen (but is about to come on screen).
    elseif ( phase == "did" ) then
        -- Called when the scene is now on screen.
        -- Insert code here to make the scene come alive.
        -- Example: start timers, begin animation, play audio, etc.
    end
end


-- "scene:hide()"
function scene:hide( event )

    local sceneGroup = self.view
    local phase = event.phase

    if ( phase == "will" ) then
        -- Called when the scene is on screen (but is about to go off screen).
        -- Insert code here to "pause" the scene.
        -- Example: stop timers, stop animation, stop audio, etc.
    elseif ( phase == "did" ) then
        -- Called immediately after scene goes off screen.
    end
end


-- "scene:destroy()"
function scene:destroy( event )

    local sceneGroup = self.view

    -- Called prior to the removal of scene's view ("sceneGroup").
    -- Insert code here to clean up the scene.
    -- Example: remove display objects, save state, etc.
end


-- -------------------------------------------------------------------------------

-- Listener setup
scene:addEventListener( "create", scene )
scene:addEventListener( "show", scene )
scene:addEventListener( "hide", scene )
scene:addEventListener( "destroy", scene )

-- -------------------------------------------------------------------------------

return scene
```

job.lua:

```js
local composer = require( "composer" )
local widget = require("widget")
local scene = composer.newScene()

-- -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- All code outside of the listener functions will only be executed ONCE unless "composer.removeScene()" is called.
-- -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

-- local forward references should go here

-- -------------------------------------------------------------------------------


-- "scene:create()"
function scene:create( event )

    local sceneGroup = self.view

    -- Initialize the scene here.
    -- Example: add display objects to "sceneGroup", add touch listeners, etc.
    local background = display.newImage("background.png")
    background.x=display.contentCenterX
    background.y=display.contentCenterY
    background.height=display.contentHeight
    background.width=display.contentWidth

      local function gotoCharacter(event)
        composer.gotoScene("character")
        print('asd')
    end

    local bottomTabButtons ={
    {  width=32, height=32, defaultFile="character.png", overFile="character_active.png", onPress=function() composer.gotoScene( "character" ) end},
    {  width=32, height=32, defaultFile="job.png", overFile="job_active.png", selected="true"},
    }
        

    local bottomBar = widget.newTabBar{
         top = display.contentHeight-40,

        buttons = bottomTabButtons
    }

 
end


-- "scene:show()"
function scene:show( event )

    local sceneGroup = self.view
    local phase = event.phase

    if ( phase == "will" ) then
        -- Called when the scene is still off screen (but is about to come on screen).


    elseif ( phase == "did" ) then
        -- Called when the scene is now on screen.
        -- Insert code here to make the scene come alive.
        -- Example: start timers, begin animation, play audio, etc.

    end
end


-- "scene:hide()"
function scene:hide( event )

    local sceneGroup = self.view
    local phase = event.phase

    if ( phase == "will" ) then
        -- Called when the scene is on screen (but is about to go off screen).
        -- Insert code here to "pause" the scene.
        -- Example: stop timers, stop animation, stop audio, etc.

    elseif ( phase == "did" ) then
        -- Called immediately after scene goes off screen.

    end
end


-- "scene:destroy()"
function scene:destroy( event )

    local sceneGroup = self.view

    -- Called prior to the removal of scene's view ("sceneGroup").
    -- Insert code here to clean up the scene.
    -- Example: remove display objects, save state, etc.
end


-- -------------------------------------------------------------------------------

-- Listener setup
scene:addEventListener( "create", scene )
scene:addEventListener( "show", scene )
scene:addEventListener( "hide", scene )
scene:addEventListener( "destroy", scene )

-- -------------------------------------------------------------------------------

return scene
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is your not inserting your display objects in to the scenegroup. Thats why its not getting deleted. Insert all your objects in to the scenegroup.

For example,

```
local background = display.newImage("background.png")
background.x=display.contentCenterX
background.y=display.contentCenterY
background.height=display.contentHeight
background.width=display.contentWidth

sceneGroup:insert(background)
```

--- This is the change. Same way insert all the objects in to this group.